# App crashes when upload data and send HTTP request

Tags: objective-c

I'm pretty dummy in Obj-C. I call `callServer` and at the same time I upload some data like image, files ...

```
 -(void) callServer
{
 dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{
        [ServerHandler sendRequest];
    });   
 }
```

Here is a `sendRequest` method, basic HTTP call that uses `NSURLSession`:

```
+ (void) sendRequest
{

    NSString *url = @"zzz";        

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            //...
            }
        } else {

            // ...
        }
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

Sometimes I get crash:

```
#2 Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x17403e500 :: NSOperation 0x184446990 (QOS: DEFAULT)
   0  libobjc.A.dylib    0x184ee315c objc_msgSend + 25
   1  YOYO               0x100766218 __82-[MyProg callServer]_block_invoke.804 + 383424
   2  YOYO               0x1007679cc __94+[ServerHandler sendRequest]_block_invoke + 389492
   3  CFNetwork          0x186a781fc __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
   4  CFNetwork          0x186a8fef8 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 148
```

**I cannot change upload process code but I can change above mentioned code.**

So question is how to make my code safe a.e.

```
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{
        [ServerHandler sendRequest];
    });   
 }
```

Why both upload data (from Swift) and HTTP request  stay on the same thread?

Comment: Can you post the complete crash? It will be helpful.

Comment: You're using a variable 'escapedURL' that isn't defined anywhere, but I assume this is just a mistake when you copied your code to SO. :) Perhaps, in your completion handler, are you trying to access some data in your response that is missing?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I have the same crash but it only happens when returning to the app after it was in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you are using NSURLSessionDataTask  instead of URLSessionUploadTask - SesionUploadTask allows uploading in the background? https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionuploadtask

Comment: I use `NSURLSessionDataTask` for HTTP POST.